# Given a private key, how do you get a public address

Tags: transactions, development, qrcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are public & private keys in an address created?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1389/how-are-public-private-keys-in-an-address-created)

I am scanning in a private key from a QR code in an app I am writting to handle the import of physical bitcoins.

Given a private key, how can I get the public key so that I can lookup its value on the block explorer?

Comment: Do you want the algorithms? Do you want code in a specific language?

Comment: Yep, that question answered it.

Comment: @RobKohr I made a practical example here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29811/1761 I hope this help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ECDSA public keys are usually generated from a random private key. The simple answer then would be, that instead of using a random private key, you use the given private key and it should generate the public key. After that, perform the [steps listed in the Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) to find out the conventional notation for the public key you can use anywhere.