# How can I create uncompressed public key in C++?

Tags: private-key, public-key, cryptography, c++, libbitcoin

I need to derive public key from my private key in uncompressed form. I know how to create compressed one with [libbitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/code/addr.cpp), but I can't find appropriate method for uncompressed form there.

Are there any other libraries in C++ which can do that?

Comment: There is this: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=644919.msg7205689#msg7205689 (not really C++), and here a discussion of the underlying: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69315/how-are-compressed-pubkeys-generated/69366?noredirect=1#comment80625_69366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about c++ or libbitcoin, but I found a public method in the bc::wallet::ec_public class

```
bool to_uncompressed(ec_uncompressed& out) const;
```

So I guess you can probably convert your `ec_public` to `ec_uncompressed`(which is just a `byte_array`) by

```
ec_uncompressed uncomp;
<public key>.to_uncompressed(uncomp);
std::cout << "Uncompressed: " << uncomp << std::endl;
```