# How do you output segwit bech32 (bc1...) / P2SH (3...) addresses from a bitcoin private key?

Tags: address, segregated-witness, address-generation, bech32-address

I have a bitcoin private key and know that it can output a segwit addresses of bech32 bc1... and p2sh 3... formats. How can this be done easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load up electrum 3.1.1+ and enable the "console" and in the console do the following to output the addresses you need by providing your private key:

**bech32 format bc1...:**

> bitcoin.address_from_private_key("p2wpkh:5Kkzs8XrJNAmf9......")

**p2sh format 3...:**

> bitcoin.address_from_private_key("p2wpkh-p2sh:5Kkzs8XrJNAmf9VQDFeG......")

you just need to prefix your private key with p2wpkh or p2wpkh-p2sh to get one of them.

Comment: Keep in mind that this function requires the WIF encoding of the private key as an input.

Comment: how do you get the WIF encoding?

Comment: I dont know about electrum but I have made a [python library](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) that can do what you want. PrivateKey.from_hex('yourkeyhere').to_public().to_address('P2WPKH')

Comment: see also here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69315/how-are-compressed-pubkeys-generated/69366?noredirect=1#comment80625_69366