# How is it possible that the same WIF Private Key generates two different addresses?

Tags: address, private-key, address-generation, p2sh

I am wondering if you can explain this.

I went here:
https://coinb.in/#newSegWit

Created the SegWit Address below:

```
3ASaGJ8h2bLn6Jha3hncBzXUKRCLyfv9bk
```

RedeemScript

```
037fa484e4b870082298d6acca0702a48714323664c647604e6461d4739feb0d9b
```

Public key

```
00147a201aa7e1cfb799dcfc2b447a0238421ae2fa60
```

Private key (WIF key)

```
KzVonapu3Cf7DaMpaqkUQ9tpsBQPBH7Yk6tXJdvMwuJSy97GK7dc
```

Then I opened Electrum  v3.1.3 and Imported WIF Pkey above.

And I got this address instead:

```
1C8ju39MFSPXNqtYDhsuB3Ek45L46dBr3G
```

So now there are two addresses,  one SegWit (or I think P2SH) starting with 3... and the legacy address from Electrum starting with 1...

Appreciate an explanation of this.

Comment: are you asking how addresses are generated or do you not understand why there are different types of addresses?

Comment: I want to understand how is it possible that the same WIF Private Key generates two different addresses? I knew that each address has its unique private key.

Comment: There was a longer thread here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69315/how-are-compressed-pubkeys-generated, which looks at the WIF keys and corresponding priv and pubkeys (though there is no P2SH involved).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same private key can be used to derive a couple of different addresses. For example, there will be a different address generated depending on whether you use a compressed or uncompressed public key in the derivation.

More relevant to your question, you can use a private key to derive a P2SH-wrapped segwit address (`3ASaGJ..` in your example), or just a plain old P2PKH address (`1C8ju3..` in your example). Both addresses are spendable using the same private key, since they are both derived from the same private key.

Note that you should **not** design a wallet to create segwit addresses using an uncompressed public key (use the compressed key only!), due to potential backwards-compatibility issues in the future.

This image from the [bitcoin wiki Address page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address) helps to illustrate this point:

[image: Bitcoin Address Derivation Map]

Comment: Thanks for all answers, I think this one is the most detailed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of addresses, see [Bitcoin Transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction), each can be created for the same recipient (key pair). For example:

- Pay to PubKey Hash (P2PKH) - These start with 1. This is basically just a hash of your public key. If you can prove you own the public key, you can spend it.
- Pay to Script Hash (P2SH) - These start with 3. This is a script that you must prove you can satisfy using your private key. There are many types of scripts as well.

They are just different ways of locking Bitcoin for a recipient, but in all of them the recipient must use the private key to satisfy the lock to spend the Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

An overview of the address types, check out: 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address

You are looking for P2SH, https://segwitaddress.org/ just scroll down and put in your compressed WIF key at the 'Details' section.

Further check out https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

BIP44, BIP49 and BIP 85 are also implemented in the Coinomi Wallet.

https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000009746-what-are-default-compatibility-and-legacy-addresses-all-about-segwit-

Comment: You meant BIP84 there. BIP85 is very different

Answer (score 0):

First a private key is created. Then a public key is generated from it. Finally it is encoded into a format.

See https://coinb.in/?verify=037fa484e4b870082298d6acca0702a48714323664c647604e6461d4739feb0d9b#verify